# Twitter Widget Cordova Application Pop up

Tags: angularjs, cordova, twitter, ionic-framework, twitter-widget

I am working on integrating twitter Widget in a tab of a Cordova application. I am using Cordova with Angularjs and ionic Framework.

I have obtained the API key needed in order to instantiate the widget and after a few attempts I got it. I attach one image ([twitter in tab](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8025470/foto1.png))

In order to do that, I create a tab, put the javascript in the main .html file and the link. So far, ok:

```
     <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/mwc2015" data-widget-id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"></a>;
```

But, the "show" begins when the user clicks on the twitter widget. 
If you want to retweet, tweet something or whatever,  twitter widget opens a new page, pop up, which is placed on top of cordova app,  and then, user can not go back. 
Device Back button doesn't work.
 You can register and send a tweet, but always this new window is on top.
I attach an image to show what the user see in the screen when any button is clicked. [twitter on top](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8025470/foto2.png)

So, you should kill Cordova app and start again.

I was wondering if someone knows how integrate the widget and the "children " pages of them , or if a javascript alternative to change target parameter of all links inside widget.js in order to open new windows inside the app.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue with Instagram, but I hope it can help as well. First of all, please install cordova InAppBrowser plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Then try to modify your config.xml file with following, adding it before *platforms* tag:

```
 <allow-navigation href="about:*" />
```